# Disabled Android ListView Items Still Selectable

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view class and am working on making it so certain items can be disabled and prevented from being selected. For the most part I have it all working but there is an edge case that I have not been able to solve.

I have implemented my code by creating an ArrayList of Integers. If the index of the item is in the list it is disabled.

I then override the areAllItemsEnabled and isEnabled functions like so:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return !mDisabledItemsList.contains(position);
}
```

Now, this all works great. I can't select the items if they are disabled.

However, there is an edge case that works like this:

1. Tap and hold on a selectable item.
2. While holding down the previous tap, tap a disabled item and hold that down as well.
3. Release your first tap.
4. The disabled item becomes selected.

This case is even weirder since the item can't be deselected by repeating the steps again.

I'm encountering this on Android ICS.

Does anyone know a way to fix this so that my disabled items can never be selected?